# Sql server importing csv files

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a list of csv files 30 files each file 120MB would like to import all at a time into Microsoft sql server.

Are there any way to import all at a time instead of doing one by one. Columns are same in all files but different file names.

Do I need to write any script for that? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning on using any particular ETL software for this? Like SSIS, Pentaho, etc., or simply using BULK INSERT from csv? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: No I haven’t try I’m newbie for that. Usually I upload one by one by right clicking on table and import.

Comment: This will take a while to code correctly. If you have access to the database server and the files are stored in the same (or accessible) server, you can script N BULK INSERTs commands to run in parallel with a .bat or .sql file. If not, you can use SSIS to load the files to the database, which is an ETL software (will require some learning to use it).

Comment: @EzLo ok thank you for that.